# Calling struts2 action class from angular JS using $http.post()

Tags: java, angularjs, post, struts2, struts-action

I facing trouble in passing data from AngularJS `$http.post()` to Action Class in JAVA.

My action class is not getting called.

**Controller.js**

[image: I am calling my action class AuthenticateLogin from the my Angular JS controller using http.post() along with sending my username and password in JSON format.]

**AuthenticateLogin.java**

[image: AuthenticateLogin]

Comment: is the request being made? check your NET tab in the browser. If it is being made please provide full request and response details

Comment: Put the code in your question - not in images!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the action extension. And potentially the namespace.

It should be

```
$http.post('AuthenticateLogin.action', data)
```

or

```
$http.post('/AuthenticateLogin.action', data)
```